# Updating data in a database in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i need to update data in a database but im getting an error i dont understand. What i have is this

```
def update_account_balance(db, number, account, change):

con =  sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('UPDATE Accounts SET (?) = (?) WHERE Number == (?)', [account, change, number])
```

and what im getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
  File "/Users/aharonsnyder1/Desktop/assignment 2/banking.py", line 168, in <module>
    cur.execute('UPDATE Accounts SET (?) = (?) WHERE Number == (?)', [account, change, number])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

I am not sure what it is not liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. SQL syntax does not use the double equal sign
2. SQLite uses either quotes, backticks, or square brackets to denote [keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).
3. Only parameters usually in `WHERE` clauses are passed in the second argument not the structural component of the SQL statement like column name.

Consider revising where you format update statement string with column name (assuming column name is the value in `account` variable) and then pass parameters:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE Accounts \
                SET [{0}] = ? \
              WHERE Number = ?'.format(account), (change, number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works

```
cur.execute('UPDATE Accounts SET (?) = (?) WHERE Number == (?)', (account, change, number))
```